# Reasonable maximum IPv6 header size

Tags: fragment, ipv6, mtu

IPv6 requires a minimum MTU of 1280. Of that, there's a minimum 40 bytes required for the IPv6 header. There's no defined limit to how many bytes the IPv6 extension headers can consume. What's a reasonable maximum to assume for normal UDP usage? I've seen it suggested, that at least 8 bytes for the fragment header, what else may crop up?

Answer (score 0):

An IPv6 header size is fixed at 40 bytes in order to make processing more efficient, not a minimum of 40, and not a variable size like IPv4.  There can be any number of optional, extension headers in an IPv6 packet, but these extension headers are controlled by the sender so calculating how large a UDP segment can be before needing to fragment it should be easy.

The fragmentation header is fixed at 8 bytes.  Routers along the path cannot fragment an IPv6 packet as they can for IPv4; the sender must pre-fragment the upper-layer datagram prior to encapsulating it in an IPv6 packet since a packet larger than the minimum MTU in a path will be dropped.  That's when you use the fragmentation header, so, if your UDP segment is small enough, you will never use the fragmentation header, otherwise you use 8 bytes for the fragmentation header.

You should look at the different types of extension headers to see if you may use any of them.  There is a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Extension_headers) on Wikipedia.

Comment: I was not under the impression that the sender can control the headers from a TCP out UDP stream, and that they'd be applied at the implementation's discretion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. What do you mean by, "a TCP out UDP stream?" TCP and UDP are separate layer-4 protocols. It is up to the sender to fragment an IPv6 packet containing TCP, UDP, or any other sort of datagram. The routers in the path will drop any packet that is too large for the next MTU, and should send back an ICMPv6 error, giving the sender the option to fragment the layer-4 datagram. Alternatively, the sender can use MTU Path Discovery ahead of time to determine if the layer-4 datagram should be fragmented.

Comment: TCP *or* UDP. What I mean is that while the sender controls the extensions in use, the user at the application level, is not setting the IPv6 headers on their UDP/TCP packets manually. So what extension headers are the UDP/TCP implementations likely to set on the user's behalf when sending over IPv6?

Comment: Did you look at the list of optional, extension headers? Certainly, if you use IPSEC, the Encapsulating Security Payload header would be used. It is up to the sender, and, you, as the programmer decide that sort of thing.

Comment: Most likely the reduced payload size of an IP packet (causing a reduction in the size of a layer-4 segment before needing to fragment) would be caused by a restricted MTU somewhere along the path, rather than by a few extension headers. The good news is that due to the nature of UDP (fire-and-forget, best-effort, unreliable protocol), the proper use of UDP limits segments to only a few dozen (a few hundred, at the most) bytes, and the segments should never be fragmented. Checking the path MTU beforehand would be a good practice for TCP because it is typically used for the larger payloads.

Comment: Maybe this will shed some light: https://github.com/anacrolix/utp/blob/master/utp.go#L39

Comment: And we circle back to my original answer. You, the programmer of the sender, decide which optional headers you will use. You many need to fragment the layer-4 segment if it is too large for the path MTU, but you can determine that ahead of time and reduce the layer-4 segment size, or you can just respond to the ICMPv6 Packet Too Big errors and fragment the layer-4 segment which adds an 8-byte fragmentation header. You can choose not to implement the other extension headers, or you may want to and just take into account the size of the extension headers you implement.

Comment: If you are lazy or paranoid, you could just assume the minimum MTU, subtract the IPv6 header size (40) and the sizes for each of the extension headers. This should be easy to calculate: "_all extension headers are optional and should only appear at most once, except for the Destination Options header, which may appear twice_." The code you link seems to assume the minimum MTU, the IPv6 header, and a fragmentation header. That may be a reasonable compromise between ignorance and paranoia, although the author call the result "_MTU_" rather than the more correct "_MSS_".

Comment: The MSS applies to TCP? uTP is a protocol built on UDP. I'm not sure the naming convention will still hold.

Comment: The MSS adjustment in an OS is for TCP.  MSS stands for Maximum Segment Size. The code is taking the MTU, subtracting the IPv6 header size and a fragmentation header size from that, and still calling it an MTU, but that it technically incorrect; the result is the UDP Maximum Segment Size (MSS). That's all I meant about the comment.